# PHP XMLWriter startDocument makes empty space

Tags: php, codeigniter, xmlwriter

```
$this->startDocument($this->_xmlVersion, $this->_charSet);
```

> XML parsing failed
>
> XML parsing failed: syntax error (Line: 1, Character: 1)
>
> ```
> Error:
> XML declaration not at beginning of document 
> Specificat`enter code here`ion:
> http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/ 
>   1:  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> Empty space before <?
> ```

How can I remove it?

Comment: You can trim from the left with [`ltrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php)

Comment: It is mostly caused by leading spaces and line breaks before `<?php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using? Your code doesn't look like `XMLWriter`:

```
$x = new XMLWriter();
$x->openMemory();
$x->startDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
var_dump($x->outputMemory());
```

This has no extra spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I can be caused by `?>` – take a look in your libraries, hooks, etc. and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

try `ob_clean()` but first make sure that output `buffering(ob_start())` is enable.

Comment: Can you explain how this would answer the OP's question?

Answer (score 0):

use ob_clean(), in my case it solve my problem.

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
$xml = new \XmlWriter();
$xml->openMemory();
$xml->startDocument($this->version, $this->encoding);
ob_clean();
```